# How to debug Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXXX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate VVV bytes)

Tags: php, memory, logging, error-handling

So, I know what the specific error I have is (Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) and what caused it.
I am not looking for the solution for that.
What I try to learn is how would I dump $_SESSION and $_REQUEST and stack trace into file when this type of errors happen, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without additional modules--once you hit memory limit it's an immediate crash.  However, You could install Xdebug module and have it log a stack trace like you indicate you want.

Here's some info on configuring the exact dump you want with xdebug: http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

You can tell xdebug you want specific variables and super globals to be dumped.  This should meet your needs.

Similarly, you could install Newrelic, but as with xdebug it's going to require a share module be loaded and you'll take a performance hit (and in this case it's not free).

Comment: I am aiming at debugging a production environment. Not sure I would want to have x-debug running there on a permanent basis. I need to see if there is an interim solution between ur suggestion and what I need.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka  I would not keep xdebug running on production perminantly, but it's a shared extension module easily turned on/off for troubleshooting.   Doesn't need to be compiled into php, just requires a reload of apache or php-fpm

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka  If this always happens at a specific line in your code, you could just dump the stuff you want to the error log right before getting there.  You could even limit it by only dumping if memory_get_usage() is close (say 80%) of reaching your limit

Comment: I tried dumping it to stderror. did not work well, still investigating why